# Focus and zoom in on a UITextField when touched?

Tags: iphone, xcode, focus, zooming, textfield

How in the world does one get the iPhone view to zoom in on a focused UITextField? I need to tap on a text field that I want to edit, and my view should zoom in to the tapped text field and pull up the keyboard (which it already does), similar to how many Internet text fields gain focus on the iPhone. Is this some type of overlay?

I've been looking everywhere for this solution but maybe I've just got the wrong terminology. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a duplicate of this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present).

In essence, there are a number of ways, but you have to program this effect manually.  A textfield is already an overlay.  You can either move it, or scroll the containing view.

Comment: This helps a lot, I'm sorry if it was a duplicate... I had no idea it required "scrolling" instead of "zooming"

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following steps.
Implement the delegate method for all textfield.connect the outlet of textfield in interface builder basically it's setting the delegate property.then in delegate property you can defined the method whatever you want to implement or wanted to do functionality.

Thanks